# install command for JAVA

Tags: 12.04, java

I am trying to install JAVA on my Ubuntu 12.04, and I followed the official instructions: http://java.com/en/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml#install

I am stuck at #3: `Unpack the tarball and install Java`. I have succesfully run `tar zxvf jre-7u7-linux-x64.tar.gz` (which just unpacks), but what is the command for installing it?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Open Applicaction>> Accessories>> Terminal

Step 2: Type commandline as below...

```
  sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
```

Step 3: Type commandline as below...

```
  apt-cache search jdk
```

Step 4: For "JAVA_HOME" (Environment Variable) type command as shown below, in "Terminal" using your installation path...

```
  export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk
```

Step 5: For "PATH" (Environment Variable) type command as shown below, in "Terminal" using your installation path...

```
  export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk/bin
```

Step 6: Check for "open jdk" installation, just type command in "Terminal" as shown below
javac
 then type java-version